# How to retrieve previous tokens in a MultiInput control when a tokenChange event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

In MultiInput control, when new tokens are added to the control, the old tokens are flushed off.

How do I get the previous tokens, when a new token(s) is added, as when the attachTokenChange event is triggered.

Here is my effort till now:

```
         var oFilter = oSmartFilterBar.getControlByKey("Filter");
         // Trying to get the current tokens when the control has focus
         oFilter.attachBrowserEvent("onfocus", function(oEvent)
         {
                oFilter._tempTokens = oFilter.getTokens();
         });
         oFilter.attachTokenChange(function(oEvent)
         {  
            var existingTokens = oFilter.getTokens();
            var oAddedTokens   = oEvent.getParameters("addedTokens").token;
         } 
    });
```

The `focus` event is not triggered and the `attachTokenChange` event is triggered every time there is a token change and only the latest values are fetched. Hence the variables `existingTokens` and `oAddedTokens` have the same value.

My question is **how do I get all the tokens in the control, before the change event is triggered**.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reconstruct the previous content of the tokens aggregation: old = new - added + removed.

The [tokenChange event](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MultiInput.html#event:tokenChange) arguments tell you which tokens have been added and which have been removed. You have to take the *type* parameter into account.

Example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ojm0VLSEm9t6VmiMOr5q?p=preview):

```js
  onTokenChange: function(oEvent){
    var newCollection = oEvent.getSource().getTokens();
    var parameters = oEvent.getParameters();
    if(parameters.type==="tokensChanged"){
      //You can ignore the added, removed and removeAll type events
      // as tokensChanged is always fired.
      var oldCollection = newCollection.filter(function(t){return parameters.addedTokens.indexOf(t)<0});
      Array.prototype.push.apply(oldCollection,parameters.removedTokens);
      //oldCollection: here you are. 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @schnodel. thanks for the answer. Can you please help me with the syntax as well. Because addTokens and removedTokens return the same result in the first call of attachTokenChange and I am not able to handle that